# 1980s/1990s SF novel about space marines from a heavy gravity planet?

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi, gravity

I'm trying to remember the title of a hard SF novel I read in the early 1990s.

The story featured space marines from a heavy gravity planet. Because of the environment they grew up and trained in, they were unbeatable when fighting on lighter gravity planets.

Comment: I know it came up in some of McCaffrey's books (that ridiculous universe with the space pirates and the dinosaurs that was everything 12 year old me had ever wanted out of life), you're not thinking of those, are you?

Comment: Some of the War World stories features heavy gravity types, too, but there wasn't a novel centered on them in that universe. More detail would *really* help because the basic idea is far from unique.

Comment: Thanks! I think the War World series might be it. I was thinking the book was a buddies-in-war story with a title something like "Heavy Planet". The books' titles and covers; the setting (a small moon orbiting a supergiant planet); and the names (the moon Haven and planet Cat's Eye) all seem familiar.

Comment: A bit earlier, but E. E. Smith's "Lensmen" books describe that as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making my comment an answer then:

Jerry Pournelle's *War World* setting (which shares a universe with his CoDominion works and his collaborations with Larry Niven *A Mote in God's Eye* and *The Gripping Hand*) was opened to other writers for contribution.

The result was four collections of short fiction and a novel.

Most of the stories are set on Haven, but one takes place on Tanith (higher than standard gravity) and several feature exiled natives of another high gravity planet. Many stories also feature Sauron Supermen. On top of that is an overarching theme that Tanith is a forge in which humans are bred for improved combative fitness.

All together this gives us several groups of physically high-performing specimens to write about.